# How to make DRY logger class with debug, info, warn and error methods that extends private method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make logger class with debug, info, warn and error methods that "extends" basic log method.

However it is not written using **DRY** principle, how can I make it **DRY**, not **WET**?

#### Code snippet

```js
const logLevels = {
  0: 'debug',
  1: 'info',
  2: 'warn',
  3: 'error',
  'debug': 0,
  'info': 1,
  'warn': 2,
  'error': 3,
}

class Logger {
  logLevel = logLevels.debug

  log(logLevel, ...messages) {
    if (logLevel >= this.logLevel) {
      const logType = logLevels[logLevel]
      messages.unshift(logType)

      console.log(...messages)
    }
  }

  debug(...messages) {
    this.log(logLevels.debug, ...messages)
  }

  info(...messages) {
    this.log(logLevels.info, ...messages)
  }

  warn(...messages) {
    this.log(logLevels.warn, ...messages)
  }

  error(...messages) {
    this.log(logLevels.error, ...messages)
  }
}

const myLogger = new Logger()
const dateNowHex = () => Date.now().toString(16)

myLogger.debug('this is a test', dateNowHex())
myLogger.info('this is a test', dateNowHex())
myLogger.warn('this is a test', dateNowHex())
myLogger.error('this is a test', dateNowHex())
```

Should I make better class composition? Can you provide examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question;

- getting the `logType` and then unshifting it seems complicated, why not

  `console.log(logLevels[logLevel], ...messages)`
- The mapping from an integer to a string and back from string to integer must be addressed to make this DRY
- This code seems a good fit for monads, which can also help with making this DRY

Other than that there is not much to say.

```js
function Logger() {
  
  const logLevels = ['debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error'];
  this.logLevel = 0;

  this.log = function log(logLevel, ...messages) {
    if (logLevel >= this.logLevel) {
      console.log(logLevels[logLevel], ...messages)
    }
  }
  
  for(let i = 0; i< logLevels.length; i++){
    this[logLevels[i]] = this.log.bind(this, i);
  }

} 

const myLogger = new Logger()
const dateNowHex = () => Date.now().toString(16) 
//debugger; 
myLogger.debug('this is a test', dateNowHex())
myLogger.info('this is a test', dateNowHex())
myLogger.warn('this is a test', dateNowHex())
myLogger.error('this is a test', dateNowHex())
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much! The logLevels is actually enum in TypeScript, just ignore it, probably important to be mentioned before. The reason behind unshift is that I am using additional coloring, so it is simplier to make it bold and then make all the messages of some color. Is there a way to make a extend based class composition? Could you please add it to your anwser as second variant? Thanks!

Comment: @RamoFX I could not get it to work as a class in jsbin :/